# How to separate Columns inside concat function with Hyphen and Comma?

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

This is the error i am getting while creating the Stored Proc below : `Incorrect syntax near ','`. 
I am trying to separate columns inside `CONCAT` function with Hyphen and Comma but if I remove Hyphen and Comma it works. I am trying to separate frist and second columns inside concat function using Hyphen and econd and third column using comma.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTypesofbooks]
        @Price AS varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @Price = REPLACE(@Price,',',''',''')
 SET @Sql = 'SELECT 
     BookID
    ,CONCAT (BookID, ' - ', Name, ' ,' ,Author ) as BookDetails
    ,[Name]
    ,[Author]

    FROM dbo.BookList A 
    Join AuthorList B
    on A.PriceId = B.PriceId
    Where 
    B.Price IN
    (

     ''' + @Price + '''
    )   
    ORDER BY BookID'
    EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comma should be double as it is a dynamic sql as.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTypesofbooks]
        @Price AS varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @Price = REPLACE(@Price,',',''',''')
 SET @Sql = 'SELECT 
     BookID
    ,CONCAT (BookID, ' - ', Name, '' ,'' ,Author ) as BookDetails
    ,[Name]
    ,[Author]

    FROM dbo.BookList A 
    Join AuthorList B
    on A.PriceId = B.PriceId
    Where 
    B.Price IN
    (

     ''' + @Price + '''
    )   
    ORDER BY BookID'
    EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I was using " instead of  ' ' earlier.